# Assigning levels in factorial design.

Tags: regression, experimental-mathematics

I am sorry if the question is too basic.

Actually while doing some experiment on 2-level factorial design, I assigned +1 to a low level and -1 to high level. I just need the sign of the regression coefficient sign and now I have to interpret this according to assigned level. 
But my question is, is this wrong ? Do I need to do the experiment again by assigning correct level ?

Actually I mentioned -1 to 10 g/l and +1 to 5 g/l.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What software are you using to analyze the data?

Comment: Well I am using matlab to do this.

Comment: Can you get access to statistical software? As a final resort, perhaps use 'R' - available free online. With statistical software you should be able to use letters for factorial levels.

Comment: I agree. As per my knowledge the regression coefficient will give negative sign. I just wanted to confirm if this is technically correct or not.